# Laravel caffeinated modules route not matching

Tags: php, laravel, module, laravel-routing

I have an interesting situation. I've installed [caffeinated modules](https://github.com/caffeinated/modules) and created a module called Blog (slug, blog). There is a default route file containing

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'blog'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        dd('This is the Blog module index page.');
    });
});
```

So if I go to `http://localhost:8000/blog` I would expect to see that text, however the route doesn't match. If I add anything else in there, it works. For example I added

```
Route::get('/test', function()
{
    dd('Test.');
});
```

to the route group and when I go to `http://localhost:8000/blog/test` it works, I see Test. But the /blog still doesn't work.

Now things get even weirder, I added the route group to my default routes file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'blog'], function ()
{
    Route::get('/', function ()
    {
        dd('test');
    });
});
```

And the route worked, sort of. When I now go to `http://localhost:8000/blog` I see the original text from the route in the module, `"This is the Blog module index page."`

Why would adding the group again in the main `app/Http/routes` file cause the route in the Blogs module to suddenly start working? Why doesn't the route in the Blogs module work in the first place?

I was wondering if perhaps it was just a problem with that module, so I tried creating another one to test, but I had the exact same results with a module of another name.

The modules and route list properly, this is the output of `module:list` and `route:list` whilst the error is occurring.

**Modules**

```
+------+----------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| #    | Name           | Slug        | Description                                                                                                                                                            | Status  |
+------+----------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| 9001 | Menu           | menu        | Standard bootstrap menu.                                                                                                                                               | Enabled |
| 9001 | Module Manager | modman      | Manages modules installed in the site, holding the name and namespace of the module. It also determines which area a module is for (e.g. content, utility, stats etc.) | Enabled |
| 9001 | Image          | image       | A content area for a single static image.                                                                                                                              | Enabled |
| 9001 | Content        | content     | Core content module that uses a simple text area and a WYSIWYG editor.                                                                                                 | Enabled |
| 9001 | Category       | category    | Creates different categories for use with blog posts                                                                                                                   | Enabled |
| 9001 | CommonArea     | common-area | Common areas are groups of content that are repeated on multiple pages. The two default areas are header and footer.                                                   | Enabled |
| 9001 | Blog           | blog        | Handles blog articles as pages and has blog preview and menu content types.                                                                                            | Enabled |
+------+----------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

**Routes**

```
+--------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method                         | URI                                 | Name                     | Action                                                                   | Middleware                                                 |
+--------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp                                 | AcpHome                  | App\Http\Controllers\AcpHomeController@index                             | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/blog                            | AcpBlogPosts             | App\Http\Controllers\AcpBlogController@index                             | web,auth                                                   |
|        | POST                           | acp/blog/create                     | AcpCreateBlog            | App\Http\Controllers\AcpBlogController@postCreate                        | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/blog/create                     | AcpCreateBlogForm        | App\Http\Controllers\AcpBlogController@getCreate                         | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/blog/{blog}/delete              | AcpDeleteBlog            | App\Http\Controllers\AcpBlogController@delete                            | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/blog/{blog}/update              | AcpUpdateBlogForm        | App\Http\Controllers\AcpBlogController@getUpdate                         | web,auth                                                   |
|        | POST                           | acp/blog/{blog}/update              | AcpUpdateBlog            | App\Http\Controllers\AcpBlogController@postUpdate                        | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/category                        | AcpCategories            | App\Http\Controllers\AcpCategoryController@index                         | web,auth                                                   |
|        | POST                           | acp/category/create                 | AcpCreateCategory        | App\Http\Controllers\AcpCategoryController@postCreate                    | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/category/create                 | AcpCreateCategoryForm    | App\Http\Controllers\AcpCategoryController@getCreate                     | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/category/{category}/delete      | AcpDeleteCategory        | App\Http\Controllers\AcpCategoryController@delete                        | web,auth                                                   |
|        | POST                           | acp/category/{category}/update      | AcpUpdateCategory        | App\Http\Controllers\AcpCategoryController@postUpdate                    | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/category/{category}/update      | AcpUpdateCategoryForm    | App\Http\Controllers\AcpCategoryController@getUpdate                     | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/content                         | AcpContent               | App\Http\Controllers\AcpContentController@index                          | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/content-area/{content}          | AcpContentAreaForm       | App\Http\Controllers\AcpContentController@getArea                        | web,auth                                                   |
|        | POST                           | acp/content-area/{content}          | AcpContentArea           | App\Http\Controllers\AcpContentController@postArea                       | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/content/menus                   | AcpContentMenus          | App\Http\Controllers\AcpContentController@index                          | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/page/column-layout/{template}   | AcpGetColumnLayout       | App\Http\Controllers\AcpPageController@columnLayout                      | web,auth                                                   |
|        | POST                           | acp/page/create                     | AcpCreatePage            | App\Http\Controllers\AcpPageController@postCreate                        | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/page/create                     | AcpCreatePageForm        | App\Http\Controllers\AcpPageController@getCreate                         | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/page/new-row                    | AcpGetNewRow             | App\Http\Controllers\AcpPageController@newRow                            | web,auth                                                   |
|        | POST                           | acp/page/{id}/update                | AcpUpdatePage            | App\Http\Controllers\AcpPageController@postUpdate                        | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/page/{id}/update                | AcpUpdatePageForm        | App\Http\Controllers\AcpPageController@getUpdate                         | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/permissions                     | AcpPermissions           | App\Http\Controllers\AcpPermissionsController@index                      | web,auth                                                   |
|        | POST                           | acp/permissions/create              | AcpPermissionsCreate     | App\Http\Controllers\AcpPermissionsController@postCreate                 | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/permissions/create              | AcpPermissionsCreateForm | App\Http\Controllers\AcpPermissionsController@getCreate                  | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/permissions/{permission}/delete | AcpPermissionsDelete     | App\Http\Controllers\AcpPermissionsController@delete                     | web,auth                                                   |
|        | POST                           | acp/permissions/{permission}/update | AcpPermissionsUpdate     | App\Http\Controllers\AcpPermissionsController@postUpdate                 | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/permissions/{permission}/update | AcpPermissionsUpdateForm | App\Http\Controllers\AcpPermissionsController@getUpdate                  | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/roles                           | AcpRoles                 | App\Http\Controllers\AcpRolesController@index                            | web,auth                                                   |
|        | POST                           | acp/roles/create                    | AcpRolesCreate           | App\Http\Controllers\AcpRolesController@postCreate                       | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/roles/create                    | AcpRolesCreateForm       | App\Http\Controllers\AcpRolesController@getCreate                        | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/roles/{role}/delete             | AcpRolesDelete           | App\Http\Controllers\AcpRolesController@delete                           | web,auth                                                   |
|        | POST                           | acp/roles/{role}/update             | AcpRolesUpdate           | App\Http\Controllers\AcpRolesController@postUpdate                       | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/roles/{role}/update             | AcpRolesUpdateForm       | App\Http\Controllers\AcpRolesController@getUpdate                        | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/templates                       | AcpTemplates             | App\Http\Controllers\AcpTemplatesController@index                        | web,auth,advanced                                          |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/templates/create                | AcpTemplatesCreateForm   | App\Http\Controllers\AcpTemplatesController@getCreate                    | web,auth,advanced                                          |
|        | POST                           | acp/templates/create                | AcpTemplatesCreate       | App\Http\Controllers\AcpTemplatesController@postCreate                   | web,auth,advanced                                          |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/templates/{template}/delete     | AcpTemplatesDelete       | App\Http\Controllers\AcpTemplatesController@delete                       | web,auth,advanced                                          |
|        | POST                           | acp/templates/{template}/update     | AcpTemplatesUpdate       | App\Http\Controllers\AcpTemplatesController@postUpdate                   | web,auth,advanced                                          |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/templates/{template}/update     | AcpTemplatesUpdateForm   | App\Http\Controllers\AcpTemplatesController@getUpdate                    | web,auth,advanced                                          |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/users                           | AcpUsers                 | App\Http\Controllers\AcpUsersController@index                            | web,auth                                                   |
|        | POST                           | acp/users/create                    | AcpUsersCreate           | App\Http\Controllers\AcpUsersController@postCreate                       | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/users/create                    | AcpUsersCreateForm       | App\Http\Controllers\AcpUsersController@getCreate                        | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/users/{user}/delete             | AcpUsersDelete           | App\Http\Controllers\AcpUsersController@delete                           | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | acp/users/{user}/update             | AcpUsersUpdateForm       | App\Http\Controllers\AcpUsersController@getUpdate                        | web,auth                                                   |
|        | POST                           | acp/users/{user}/update             | AcpUsersUpdate           | App\Http\Controllers\AcpUsersController@postUpdate                       | web,auth                                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | blog                                |                          | Closure                                                                  | web                                                        |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | blog/test                           |                          | Closure                                                                  | web                                                        |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | category                            |                          | Closure                                                                  | web                                                        |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | common-area                         |                          | Closure                                                                  |                                                            |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | content                             |                          | Closure                                                                  |                                                            |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | image                               |                          | Closure                                                                  | web                                                        |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager                 |                          | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\LfmController@show               | web,auth,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/crop            |                          | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\CropController@getCrop           | web,auth,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/cropimage       |                          | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\CropController@getCropimage      | web,auth,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/delete          |                          | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\DeleteController@getDelete       | web,auth,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/deletefolder    |                          | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\FolderController@getDeletefolder | web,auth,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/doresize        |                          | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\ResizeController@performResize   | web,auth,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/download        |                          | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\DownloadController@getDownload   | web,auth,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/folders         |                          | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\FolderController@getFolders      | web,auth,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/jsonitems       |                          | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\ItemsController@getItems         | web,auth,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/newfolder       |                          | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\FolderController@getAddfolder    | web,auth,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/rename          |                          | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\RenameController@getRename       | web,auth,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | laravel-filemanager/resize          |                          | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\ResizeController@getResize       | web,auth,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | laravel-filemanager/upload          |                          | Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\controllers\UploadController@upload          | web,auth,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | login                               |                          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm                   | web,guest                                                  |
|        | POST                           | login                               |                          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                           | web,guest                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | logout                              |                          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout                          | web                                                        |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | menu                                |                          | Closure                                                                  |                                                            |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | modman                              |                          | Closure                                                                  | web                                                        |
|        | POST                           | password/email                      |                          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail          | web,guest                                                  |
|        | POST                           | password/reset                      |                          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset                       | web,guest                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | password/reset/{token?}             |                          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm               | web,guest                                                  |
|        | POST                           | register                            |                          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register                        | web,guest                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | register                            |                          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm            | web,guest                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | {page?}                             | Page                     | App\Http\Controllers\PageController@index                                | web                                                        |
+--------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What does this mean exactly `however the route doesn't match`

Comment: @revo When I browse to the route it doesn't show me the text, instead it ends up at my catch all route right at the end.

Comment: Are you sure it is not a conflict caused by the same route which is defined earlier? (E.g. somewhere in laravel `routes.php`)

Comment: No, there is no other route for Blog, and as I mentioned when I do add a conflict it shows me the original route in the modules rather than the conflict.

Comment: if you disable caffeinated modules then it works? with a plain laravel installation these routes should work just fine

Comment: @paweldubiel no, because it is a module, if I disable modules the route file won't even be loaded...

Comment: How does your catchall route look? I suspect that gets registered before your modules. You could take a look if the stock `RouteServiceProvider` gets registered before `ModuleServiceProvider` (`config/app.php`, in the `providers` array)

Comment: @Dencker no, that's not it. The catchall route is the very last route and `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,` is the very last provider registered. My catch all is `Route::get('/{page?}', ['as' => 'Page', 'uses' => 'PageController@index']);`

Comment: Can you add the (anonymized) output of `module:list` and `routes:list`?

Comment: @Dencker I've done that.

Comment: That's so weird. It's obviously registered in the correct order. I'm blank.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot post a comment, but does `php artisan route:list` reveal anything useful, ie. do you see a `/blog` route or `/blog/` perhaps.

Comment: Yes, I do see a `blog` route. It's listed, but it still doesn't show.

Comment: It is a strange one, do you perhaps have a confused cached route file, perhaps clear the cache `php artisan route:clear`. Also do you have the same problem with `/content` and `/category`

Comment: I'll try the route clear in the morning, but yes this happens for every module.

Comment: I created a new Laravel 5.2 instance (I presume you using 5.2?), installed caffeinated modules, managed to create two modules and both `/blog` and `/category` resolve correctly. From your current routes it looks like you have an existing app and trying to convert the different pieces into modules. Only advice I have left is to perhaps start a new Laravel project, create the modules you want and then migrate from the existing base to the new install.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried by adding a extra route before **/** route?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'blog'], function ()
{
    Route::get('/check', function ()
    {
        dd('check');
    });


    Route::get('/', function ()
    {
        dd('test');
    });
});
```

Try this. Hope will work for you.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. The extra route works (I'd see check) but the index route still wont.

Answer (score 0):

Your route is registered as evident from the  `route:list` output.

The only issue I can see is that there is a `{page?}` route which if defined before `blog`will be called when you visit `/blog`.

Try `dd()` on your page route.

Comment: `{page?}` is the very last route defined. It's a catch all at the end. I know that's the case because `/blog/test` works fine.

Comment: @Styphon `{page?}` will only catch the first segment. So it will catch all single segment routes not multisegment. So `/blog` will be matched not `/blog/test` by this route. Try some multisegment route that is not defined and see if it's matched by `{page?}` route.

Answer (score 0):

> **namespace** parameter in your group attribute array to specify the
>   namespace for all controllers within the group

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'blog', 'prefix' => 'blog'], function()
{
     Route::get('/', function()
     {
        dd('This is the Blog module index page.');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Route **{page?}** is executed before modules and match to one segment routes in your modules.

Run this route to see order of your routes

```
Route::get('routes', function() {
    $router = $this->app->make('router');
    $routes = $router->getRoutes();

    foreach($routes AS $route)
    {
        dump($route->uri());
    }
    dd($routes);
});
```

For route:

```
Route::get('{slug?}', 'PageController@getPage')
    ->name('page')
    ->where('slug', '[a-zA-Z0-9_]*');
```

In my app I've created file *App/Routing/Matching/SlugValidator.php*

```
<?php namespace App\Routing\Matching;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
use Illuminate\Routing\Matching\ValidatorInterface;
use App\Models\Page;

class SlugValidator implements ValidatorInterface
{
    /**
     * Validate a given rule against a route and request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Route  $route
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return bool
     */
    public function matches(Route $route, Request $request)
    {
        if ($route->getName() == 'page') {
            return (bool) $page = Page::where('slug', '=', $request->segment(1))
                ->where('status', '=', PAGE::STATUS_ACTIVE)->count();
        }

        return true;
    } // matches()
} // SlugValidator
```

And in *App/Http/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php* in boot function:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Route as R;
use App\Routing\Matching\SlugValidator;

[ ....]

public function boot()
{
    R::$validators = array_merge(R::getValidators(), [new SlugValidator]);
    parent::boot();
}
```